# Regular Expressions - Greater than / less than conditionals allowed?

Tags: regex

I have a page that returns a list of buyables (i.e. number available) and their associated product ID:

{"buyable":1,"prodId":444123,"

I want to retrieve the product ID from the page with a buyable number greater than 1, is it possible to do this within a regular expression?

EDIT: I have the following regular expression to grab the appropriate groups, but am not finding a good way to setup a conditional statement within the Regular Expression to filter out the non-"1" buyable items.

```
.*\"buyable\":([0-9]+),.*\"prodId\":([0-9]+),
```

or am I drastically overthinking this and I just need to use the below instead?

```
.*\"buyable\":([1-9]+),.*\"prodId\":([0-9]+),
```

Comment: [2-9] if it's a single digit.  If not, nope.

Comment: `([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)` matches any integer strictly greater than 1. so you *can*. But you *shouldn't*. Parse it and loop over it instead.

Comment: You can also use negative lookahead to reject 1, but it's not any better.

Comment: Thanks! I will see if I can configure JMeter to dump the values into a parsable array instead.   EDIT: Why the downvote? I'm trying to learn!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using json path to tackle this problem.

Anyway, if you want to use a regex, then you could use:

```
.*\"buyable\":(?:[02-9]|[0-9]{2,}),.*\"prodId\":([0-9]+),
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/MgGW8r/1)**

[image]